# Javascript onclick quotation marks problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, string

I dont know how to make this onclick work.
The var foodId is a string and I need to put quotation marks around it.

```
$('#results').append('<div onclick="() => cart('+ foodId +')"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique, using `JSON.stringify` and escaping `"`, `&`, `<` and so on.

```js
var foodId = `don't "call" me & &amp; <something>`;

function esc_attr(string) {
  if (!string) {
    return "";
  }
  return ("" + string).replace(/[&<>"'\/\\]/g, function(s) {
    return {
      "&": "&amp;",
      "<": "&lt;",
      ">": "&gt;",
      '"': '&quot;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      "/": '&#47;',
      "\\": '&#92;'
    }[s];
  });
}

$('#results')
  .append('<button onclick="cart(' + esc_attr(JSON.stringify(foodId)) + ')">click</button>');

function cart(str) {
  console.log(str)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your post.
But The string in foodId hasnt any " in it. 
I just need that the rendered html looks like that: 

cart("46hkghndjgd")

currently it looks like:

cart(46hkghndjgd)

Comment: It should work with any string. See my snippet above

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery so don't add elements with inline event listeners. Use it to add an element with a class to the page, and then have it listen out for events from those elements.

Here's a basic example.

```js
const items = [ 'orange', 'apple' ];
const button1 = `<button class="add" data-food-id="${items[0]}">Add ${items[0]}</button>`;
const button2 = `<button class="add" data-food-id="${items[1]}">Add ${items[1]}</button>`;

// Append the button, and then listen out
// for events from its elements with the `add` class
$('#results')
  .append(button1)
  .on('click', '.add', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  const item = $(this).data('food-id');
  console.log(`I have clicked "${item}"`);
}

// We can add a new button, and its events will
// still be recognised
$('#results').append(button2);
```

```css
.add { margin-right: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: You didn't escape for the attribute. This would fail in case of `const item = 'where "did" it go?';`

Comment: @ITgoldman it's a food id, not a complicated string with quotes.